# Woocommerce group order total by custom field date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get a overview of all dates within a time period (like 2020), and aggregate the order total.
So each date should show the total revenue for that day.
See example below:

| Date | Total revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 25-12-2020 | 10.000 USD |
| 24-12-2020 | 8.763 USD |

But instead of grouping the orders by date, I would like to group the orders by a custom field called "pickup_date", which is formatted as: dd-mm-yy.

If someone could provide a sql solution and an example of how to loop through the results and output a table like the one I have provided above, I would really appreciate it.
Hope someone can help - I find Woocommerce SQL very confusing.

Comment: You must group by date but output the expression which you need.

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can always build a query on your functions.php to fetch all the data you need and this is a sample query I am not so sure if it fits on results that you need but you can change this one.

```
global $wpdb;

$data = $wpdb->get_results("
 SELECT
   b.meta_value as pickup_date,
   c.meta_value as total
 FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items as a
 LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as b ON b.order_item_id = a.order_item_id AND 
 b.meta_key = 'pickup_date'
 LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as c ON c.order_item_id = a.order_item_id AND 
 b.meta_key = '_line_total'
 GROUP BY b.meta_value
 ");
```